# How to help a 3 year old to sleep better?

Tags: pre-schooler, sleep

My 3 year old doesn't go to sleep until late after 11pm and wakes up by 7.30am. Is this ok? She sleeps for 2 to 3 hours in the afternoon until 5pm.

Since birth she hasn't slept properly.

Comment: Does she go to bed before 11?

Comment: Have you tried changing/reducing the nap time?  Does she seem sleepy during the day?  What makes you concerned - is it the difficulty getting to sleep at night, the total hours slept, etc.?  Have you spoken to her pediatrician?

Comment: Define more clearly what you mean by "properly." Because she doesn't go to sleep before 11pm?

Comment: So, your question actually is, how can you help her to go to sleep earlier?

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @Nilah's answer. 11 to 15 hours of sleep is normal for a child her age.

Physically draining activities are usually the best for getting a child into a normal sleep pattern. For example, my daughter is 4; I wake her up as I get ready for work at 7am. As soon as she gets up, I make her breakfast, sit her at the table and let her eat while I finish getting ready. By 7:30am she is done with breakfast and heading into the garage to play with her toys. By 11am she's eating lunch and then her and her brother go into the backyard with my wife to run around and play. They don't come back inside for at least an hour. She eats dinner at 5pm, bath at 6, and in bed by 7:30pm; I let her play in her room or watch her T.V. if she wants, but it's lights out by 8pm and she's going to sleep, usually she's out cold on her own around 7:45pm.

That nap in the afternoon is one of the biggest issues keeping her up until 11pm. If she doesn't take a nap so late, or doesn't take one at all, and she's physically exhausted from playing all day, she will go to bed at what we as adults consider a decent hour.

Answer (score 0):

11 to 15 hours of sleep is normal for a 3-year-old. To sleep better make her play more physical games like riding bicycle, jumping, running etc. in the evening and a fulfilled dinner around 7pm and change her sleeping to 9 pm.

Answer (score 0):

At the age of three a child rapidly grows and the best time of growing a child is during deep sleep. Sleeping 11 to  15 hours daily is the best cycle for three ager. However I have few suggestion which increase a child sleeping hours.
1   diet having solid ingredients
2   drinking of milk at least 250 ml   milk before sleep at night
3.   Involve in physical activities in evening 
4.   Avoid him to spent more time in front of tv, laptop or cell phone.